# Does the limit $\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $ \,f :[0,\infty) \to R$ be the function  such that for any positive  $a$, the sequence  $\left\lbrace \,f(an)\right\rbrace$ converges to $0$. 
>   Does  the limit $\ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\,$ exist?

My  answer : yes, take  $\;f_n(x) = e^{{-nax}^2}$.

Comment: You can't just take *a* function.

Comment: why ?@See-WooLee..but its  satisfied the given condition

Comment: It seems that the question asks for *any* given function $f$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(an)=0$ for all $a>0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't just take a *single* function with the property you're talking about and use that to argue that *all* functions have this property.

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Is it between $40$ and $50$?
>
> Answer: Yes, take $n=42$.

This is obviously not a valid proof that every natural number is between $40$ and $50$.

Instead, you should focus your effort of finding a *counterexample* to the property. It's not difficult to construct one once you've decided to try.

Comment: Is there any counterexample? I can't find..

Comment: @See-WooLee: Apologies for my now deleted harsh comment. I had you confused for the OP. Yes, there are many counterexamples, and they are easy to construct simply by brute force.

Comment: @See-WooLee: Basically, you need some arbitarrily large $a$ where $f(a)\ge 1$, for example. Choose some $a$ for this role, and for each one you choose, also chose values for $f(na)$ so they converge to $0$. If your initial choices are _random_, it is almost certain that the $na$ sequences won't collide with each other. Everything you don't need a value for you just map to $0$.

Comment: Oh, I thought $f$ should be a continuous function. I’m not sure but I saw that the statement is true for continuous functions (but I don’t know the proof. Maybe I’m wrong)

Comment: @See-WooLee: At least I haven't been able to think of a way to make a continuous counterexample either.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, does the example I give not construct a continuous one? (there may be some blow up at $0$, but just cut the function off, and replace it by something.)

Comment: @CWL: I'm afraid I have not managed to understand what you have in mind with your hints at all.

Comment: So the function $g(x) = \sin 1/x$ for $x \ge 1$ and linearly extended to $0$ for in domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: @CWL: In that case the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ does exist (it is $0$), so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: Oops, you are right. In that case Uskebasi probably has the right answer. I am so sorry. And yes, the examples I can come up now are all discontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you few hints.

- Try with something discontinuous  (maybe something that is zero except for some points)
- Look at the points considered by the problem. They are all of the form $an$ for some $a>0$ fixed. This means that you are only looking at integer multiples of $a$. What happens if your function is defined $1$ on $b^n$, where $b$ is some noninteger number larger than $1$ (to be choosen)?